# How to call function with type cid in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I need to call the function which has cid ass attribute from jdbc.
The documentation says about type cid - "Command identifiers are also 32-bit quantities."
I create simple function with cid

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simplecid(in_param cid)
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
 RAISE NOTICE 'Test cidtype';
END;
$function$;
```

I'm trying to call this from the console.
SELECT "simplecid"(123);
And i get this error:

> : ERROR: function simplecid(integer) does not exist
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I'm trying to do an explicit cast:
SELECT "sa_db_test.simplecid"(cast(1 as cid));

> SQL Error [42846]: ERROR: cannot cast type integer to cid

I'm try to use another type.
SELECT "simplecid"(cast('a' as cid));

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function simplecid(cid) does not exist
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Also i tried call it from jdbc and i have the same error:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ call sa_db_test.simplecid(?) }");
    callableStatement.setLong(1, 34L);
    callableStatement.execute();
```

I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
> function sa_db_test.simplecid(bigint) does not exist   No
> function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
> add explicit type casts.

Comment: You can cast `text` to `cid`.  See if `(1::text)::cid` works.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I try it.  SELECT "sa_db_test.textTest"((1::text)::cid); but i have the same error: ERROR: function sa_db_test.textTest(cid) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Thank you so mutch. Your approach is work correct. I do not know why, but it worked only after creating a couple of new functions, apparently I have problems with the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals (type `unknown`) can be converted to any data type. So you have three ways to write a constant of type `cid`:

- `CID '123'`
- `'123'::cid` or `CAST ('123' AS cid)`
- `cid('123')`

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.10.2) for details.

Comment: Thank you. It's work.  In jdbc, apparently, the best way would be to add the query itself with the transformation like conn.prepareCall("{ call test4(?::cid) }")  or is it possible to do this using methods built into the api of the jdbc library ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of cases to call it from jdbc. And i founded two:

1. This case is simple. The query is put explicit type casting.

   CallableStatement callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ call
   test4(?::cid) }")
   callableStatement.setString(1, "123");
   ...
2. The second case is more preferably for me, because i can't change query in prepareCall (this is happening elsewhere):

   ```
   CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call cid_test(?, ?, ?) }");
    callableStatement.setObject(1, "321", Types.OTHER);
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, (Types.OTHER));
    callableStatement.setObject(3, "123",  Types.OTHER);
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, (Types.OTHER));
    callableStatement.execute();
    System.out.println(((PGobject) callableStatement.getObject(2)).getValue());
    System.out.println(((PGobject) callableStatement.getObject(3)).getValue());
   ```

It is good to know that a string with letters will not be converted to cid and zero value will be returned in response